# Kafka independent consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Kafka and trying to validate my design. Below is what I have.

I have one producer publishing to one topic and have a bunch of containers (where my web app is deployed) where a consumer is running on each one of the containers. These consumers are not in the consumer-group and consuming messages independently. Each consumer should read all messages from the topic.
e.g. suppose there are 3 messages on the topic - m0, m1, m2 then consumer1 to consumerN should read m0, m1, m2 independently.
Each consumer is committing offset as soon as it processes the read messages. Whenever there is a re-deployment of my web application, all consumers go down and are restarted. They are supposed to start reading from their last committed offset.

For this set-up, as I said all my consumers are not in any consumergroup and I suppose this should make them read messages independently, please confirm that is right? Is there any flaw in this design?

Comment: Can you confirm that in the consumers' logs there is a message about successful offset committing?

Comment: Well, I haven't started implementation yet. Before starting to implement this topology, I need to make sure I am going in the right direction.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, Yes ! It will work as you would have thought. N number of containers will be on N number of consumer groups and as long as they can commit the last consumed offset, restarting the containers would cause no data loss or duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your design is just missing a small thing, each of your container must define a different (kafka) consumer group and reuse it at restart. Otherwise a random group id will be assigned to each consumer at each startup and therefore they will not pick up consuming where they left at shutdown.

Comment: this is more a matter of configuration rather than design. Also it is client specific. e.g. Both Spring Kafka and Confluent Kafka will require you to specify a `group.id`. Not sure abt plain Java consumer, but probably even there it is not true anymore. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2648

Answer (score 0):

Your design looks sound to me, based on your own statement that each consumer should consume all of the messages. As Kafka maintains offset commit per consumer group/topic/partition, each of your consumer will have the freedom to process and commit offset independently.

Take a look at this [link](http://cloudurable.com/blog/kafka-architecture/index.html) to understand Kafka's basic architecture.

You could also explore a special internal topic created by Kafka called `__consumer_offsets` where offsets are stored for each consumer group id.

In practice, whether a consumer will be able to read where it left off after a restart is also determined by the topic's retention period. If downtime exceeds retention period, there could be message losses